# centering a rectangle in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, rectangles

I am trying to create a rectangle in the center of a jframe. I tried with insets but i had not any luck. I have made the following class for the rectangle:

```
    public class RectDraw extends JComponent{

    Shape rect;
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D graph2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        graph2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        rect = new Rectangle2D.Float(50,50,15,15);


        graph2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        graph2.fill(rect);
        graph2.draw(rect);

    }


}
```

And the main:

```
public class TheMain{


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Screen screen = new Screen();
        RectDraw rect = new RectDraw();
        screen.add(rect, BorderLayout.CENTER);

}
```

And this is the class screen:

```
    public class Screen extends JFrame{


    public Screen(){
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setTitle("Testing");
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

So what i should change in order to put this rectangle in the center of the jframe?

Thanks!

Comment: `(getWidth()-width)/2` used as the `x` value of the `Rectangle2D` will center the rectangle horizontally if `width` is used as width of rectangle. Guess how you'd go about centering the height?